# What about $f$ if $\frac{d\left(xf(x)-x\right)}{dx} \geq 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

I know that my function $f$ must satisfy the following condition for $x \geq 0:$
$$\frac{d\left(xf(x)-x\right)}{dx} \geq 0.$$
What can I say about $f?$ I am curious about its possible sign or variations with respect to $x$.

I have investigated Grönwall's inequality to find an upper bound for $f$ but it seems useless in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

Note that

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}(xf(x)-x)&=xf'(x)+f(x)-1\\\\
&=x(f(x)-1)' +(f(x)-1)
\end{align}$$

Now, let $u(x)=1-f(x)$ and $\beta(x)=-\frac1x$ and apply Gronwall's Inequality on the interval $[a,b]$ where $0<a<b$.

---

> Alternatively, simply integrate the given inequality over an interval for which it applies.  What do you find directly about the bound on $f(x)$ in that interval without the need to appeal to Gronwall's Inequality?

Comment: Take any $0<a<b$ and apply Gronwall's Inequality on the interval $[a,b]$.  Now, can you find the bound for $f(x)$ in terms of $a$ and $f(a)$?

Comment: By doing so I find $u(x) < u(a) \times \exp \left[\int_a^x{-\frac{dx}{x}}\right] =  u(a) \times \exp \left[-\ln\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\right] = u(a) \times \frac{a}{x}$. Replacing $u$ by $1-f$ and taking $a=0$, I end up with $f\left(x\right)>1$.

Comment: You assume $a>0$.  So, not quite.  You should find that $$f(x)\ge 1+\frac ax \,\left(f(a)-1 \right)$$for $0<a<x$

Answer (score 1):

From the mean value theorem it follows that if a function has positive derivative on an interval, then it is increasing there. Thus, with $x_2>x_1$ you can conclude that
$$
x_2f(x_2)-x_2>x_1f(x_1)-x_1.
$$
You can of course rearrange the terms if you want. If there is something more specific you want to say, then please update your question.

Comment: If I take $x_2 = x$ and $x_1 = 0$, I find $f\left(x\right)>1$. Thanks!